# Cycles in Selenium test cases - java

Tags: java, selenium, cycle, testcase

Example, there is a web page in which there is an ability to move to another page with button - "Next Page". Does selenium provide an ability to cycle through this pages, I have one page with 100 "Next Page" butttons, and second with 200 "Next Page". Can i make something like

```
do { 
selenium.click("next page");
}while (next_page exists);
```

This an example, but I hope you understood the idea.

Comment: If you don't specify a condition It might go to infinite loop.

Comment: I trying to find out how to write a correct condition for do while cycle

Answer (score 2):

Of course.  Selenium can automate pagination.

Let the id's of the page nums be `pageX` - `X` being the page number.

in Java (pseudo) -

```
public void nextPage() {
  if (selenium.isElementPresent("css=a#page" + (i+1)))
    selenium.click("css=a#page" + (i+1));
}
```

Just wrap that in a loop, like you did up there.

**EDIT**: I noticed in the comments you want it in a `do{}while()`

```
public boolean hasNextPage() {
  return selenium.isElementPresent("css=a#page" + (i+1));
}
```

So your loop would be -

```
do {
  nextPage();
} while (hasNextPage())
```

do

Comment: Thank you for your help. But if my buttons are link='link name', link names always changes, is there a possibility to go through then with a loop?

Comment: Read the API, found a getAllLinks(), but it gets the ID of link, but I don't have any ID for link elements.